# Saving uploaded images to session storage Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, session, upload, grid

Am using file upload controller to browse images and the selected images should be previewed in the page as image thumbnails.  The design is responsive.

```
<input type="file" id="imageSelector" multiple="multiple" />
```

Below is the code I used,

```
var uploadImageCtrl = document.querySelector('#imageSelector');
uploadImageCtrl.addEventListener('change', function () {
    var files = this.files;
    for(var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        createImageGrid(this.files[i]);
    }
}, false);  


function createImageGrid(imageFile) {
   // Using FileReader to display the image content
   var imageReader = new FileReader();
   var id;

    imageReader.onload = function (e) {
        id = "image" + ($("#grid > div").length + 1);
        var imgGridHTML = '';
        gridHTML += '<div class="post-box col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4"> <img class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" value="' + id + '" ';
        gridHTML += ' src="' + e.target.result + '">';

        gridHTML += '<div class="editCheckContainer">';

        gridHTML += '<input type="checkbox" value="' + id + '" name="imageCheck" pull-right"> </div> </div>';

        $(gridHTML).appendTo("#grid");
        imgGridHTML = '';       
    }
    imageReader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
}
```

I added a checkbox to select the images. And on clicking the Next button in the page, the selected images should be saved to sessionStorage, so that I can access it in the next page.

```
var images = [];
$(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function(e) {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {  
        images.push({id:$(this).attr('value'), src:$(this).parent().prev().attr('src')});
    }
}

$('#next').click(function(){
    var response = sessionStorage.setItem('selectedGridImages', JSON.stringify(images));
}
```

But the images array is not getting saved. Could anyone suggest what is the issue here or an alternative way to do this?

Thanks....